# Why were only 12 people on Gus's payroll at the beginning of Season 5?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* S05E02, "Madrigal", Lydia shows Mike a list of 11 people who are on Gus's payroll. Including Mike, this would make 12 people on Gus's payroll.

Only, wouldn't it actually be 15?

In the season four finale, "Face Off", Walt murders 3 of Gus's men:

- the first one, Tyrus, is killed when Walt has Hector Salamanca detonate a bomb intended to kill Gus.
- the second and third man are shot down by Walt when Walt goes to release Jessie from captivity in the lab.

Shouldn't it be 15 men on Gus's payroll and not 12?

It is possible that Gus would choose not to pay the families of any of the men who had died but the show, as far as I am aware, does not establish this one way or another.

Is this a plot hole, am I missing something, or does the show just not provide enough information to make an assessment one way or another?

Comment: Maybe not all people involved in Gus operations were in jail (and those who weren't are not a threat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They most likely didn't have them on the list.  According to the [Wiki for Gus' empire](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire):

**Management & Finance:**

- Gustavo Fring, boss

  - Barry Goodman, Fring's personal doctor
  - Dan Wachsberger, attorney for all of Fring's men and the one managing the legacy money to keep them silent
  - Dennis Markowski, Fring's guy who runs the laundry
  - Peter Schuler, Fring's contact at Madrigal Electromotive GmbH

    - Lydia Rodarte-Quayle, An associate of Fring and Schuler who was their go between and managed the distribution of the methylamine
    - Ron Forenall, a Madrigal warehouse foreman

**Enforcement:**

- Mike Ehrmantraut, Fring's second-in-command

  - Victor, Fring's primary enforcer
  - Tyrus Kitt, Fring's secondary enforcer

    - Chris Mara, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Jack McGann, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Anthony Perez, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Andrew Holt, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Isaac Conley, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - William Moniz, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Harris Boivin, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Raymond Martinez, employed as Los Pollos Hermanos security[1](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gus%27_Drug_Empire)
    - Nick, one of Gus' security forces
    - Diego, one of Gus' security forces

**Distribution:**

- Rival Dealers, Two dealers working for Fring
- Tomás Cantillo, Lookout for the dealers

**Manufacturing**

- Walter White, Fring's first primary cook
- Gale Boetticher, Walt's first assistant
- Jesse Pinkman, Walt's second assistant and later his primary cook

  - Duane Chow, Fring's supplier of chemicals from Golden Moth Chemical

That's 25 employees.  I'm not sure how many died prior to that episode, but it's likely that they only had 11 under surveillance.

Comment: I would say that Tyrus is primary enforcer and Victor is secondary -- Victor seems a little too eager, Tyrus has more "command presence:" -- why do you say Victor is primary?

Comment: @releseabe - Because, as stated in the answer, the Breaking Bad Wiki said so.  If you click on the link I provided, you'll see that hierarchy verbatim.  I know Wikis aren't "The Bible", but usually Fandom Wikis are pretty accurate.